# Importing HoloEverywhere to existing project as Library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to import [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) i've downloaded it into my eclipse and tried to import it as a library

> properties -> on the Android tab -> add library

and then extend my SherlockFragmentActivity to org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity just as the mirgration guide suggest it.

My problem is that the moment tha I added the HoloEverywhere Library into my project all my classes would resolve my project's R. What am I doing wrong??
Thank you for your time

Comment: Maybe the issue was related to lint warnings that had not been cleared?

Answer (score 2):

1) Try to clean up your Project. (Project>Clean) 2) try to use **import com.example.yourproject.R** I hope that helps you.